# macOS Catalina fails to open certain apps with LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10810

Tags: macos, mac, macos-catalina

I'm not sure why, but for some reason adobe creative cloud and Xampp won't open on my mac. When I open them normally through finder or with the dock they bounce up and down once before doing nothing. And when I try to open them through the terminal I get an error
`LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10810`

[image: failed to open with error -10810 message]

For the case of Xampp this has happened ever since I have installed it and I haven't been able to get it to open ever. However, for the case of creative cloud this is a new occurrence. None of my adobe apps have been affected however. I have tried a clean install and restored from a time machine backup as I was also having an issue in which my mac will not install any .pkg files. However, this did not fix the issue. I've done a bit of digging online but have not yet been able to find any solution or much reference to this error code at all. Does anyone have an idea of what might be going on?

Comment: Sorry, we can't accept images of code or errors. Post those as text, so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Comment: Does this question help you? [macos - LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10810 Can't open 'Install OS X Yosemite.app' - Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/181026/lsopenurlswithrole-failed-with-error-10810-cant-open-install-os-x-yosemite)

Comment: @DavidPostill - I grabbed a more comprehensive one & copied it over.

Comment: @Tetsujin Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Copied from my answer at [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/228748/85275)

`LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error ...` is often an execute permissions error.

You can text the permissions of the overall app from terminal
`ls -l path/to/app`
but if that looks OK, you may need to test the executable within the app
`ls -l path/to/app/Contents/MacOS/app`

Simple example using Calculator…

```
$ ls -l /Applications/Calculator.app/Contents/MacOS/Calculator
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  143648  3 Dec 06:43  
/Applications/Calculator.app/Contents/MacOS/Calculator
```

If you don't see the `x` execute permission, you can add it with
`chmod +x path/to/app/Contents/MacOS/app`

There's an alternative approach which *may* work.
On first run, rather than double-clicking, right-click & select Open from the drop menu. This will bypass Gatekeeper's quarantine & allow it to run. It should then remember this for subsequent launches.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, different apps appear to have different levels of access, however, I cannot seem to find any differences with creative cloud or it's executable. Interestingly xampp said -rwxrwxrwx@ instead of the usual drwxr-xr-x I tried adding that permission to it as you suggested however that did not change anything. I also tried your 'open' method however that didn't work. Thanks for the help.